# Let $M$ be a semisimple right module over the ring $R$, and let $T:= End_{R}(M)$, $M$ is a semisimple left module over the ring $T$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, homological-algebra

Let $M$ be a semisimple right module over the ring $R$, and let $T:= End_{R}(M)$, I want to prove that $M$ is a semisimple left module over the ring $T$. As $M$ is semisimple we have the following descomposition into simple modules

$$M=S_{1} \oplus S_{2} \oplus ....\oplus S_{n}$$.

I want to find a similar descomposition into simples for $M$ as a left module ove $T$. So far, I have  succesfully proved that if $S$ is a simple right module over $R$, then $S$ is a left simple module over $End_{R}(S,S)$. But what I need to kill the original problem is to show that $S$ is left simple module over $T$ in order to use the original semisimple descomposition for $M$ as left $R$ module.

I have been trying this problem for a while and know it has been asked a few times but still see te explanations so foggy for being honest, also there is no even sketches of this proof online. So I would really aprreciate help proving this.

Comment: I'm at least going to [link your previous version of this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3518672/29335) because I still don't understand where you got stuck, and there is a lot of explanation there.  Wiping it out isn't exactly a nice thing to do.

Comment: Didnt try to be rude just trying to got a simpler proof. First problem I got is how I prove the $M_{\alpha}$ you defined are indeed sets and no classes @rschwieb

Comment: The $M_\alpha$ I defined are subsets of a set (the set $M$!).  Worrying if they are classes is not necessary.

Comment: Subsets of which set? The set is the sum of simples isomorphic to $S_{\alpha}$ ? @rschwieb

Comment: **the set $M$**, as I said above.  $M_\alpha$ is the sum of simple submodules of $M$ which are $R$ isomorphic to $S_\alpha$.

Comment: First doubt cleared. In order to show $M_{\alpha}$ is $T$ submodule of $M$ I onl proved scalar property. Let $m \in M_{\alpha}$, then $m= \sum x$ where each $x \in S$ and $S \cong S_{\alpha}$, taking $f \in T=End(M)$ I have $fm=f(m)=f( \sum x)=\sum f(x)$ and each $f(x) \in S$ is this right? @rschwieb

Comment: No, that isn't a sound argument.  It looks as if you're pretending all the copies of $S$ are the same set.  It is much simpler just to note that if $S$ is a simple submodule of $M$ isomorphic to $S_\alpha$, then $f(S)$ is either zero or isomorphic to $S$. Either way it lies in $M_\alpha$.  So each element of $End(M)$ acting on the left maps $M_\alpha$ into $M_\alpha$

Comment: So you are saying that $f(M_{\alpha}) \subseteq M_{\alpha}$ right? @rschwieb

Comment: Yes, indeed!  In particular $f(x)\in M_\alpha$ for every $x\in M_\alpha$.

Comment: Does it bother you if I refer $M_{\alpha}$ as $M_{\alpha}=\sum_{i \in I} N_{i}$ where each $N_{i} \cong S_{\alpha}$ for every $i \in I$? @rschwieb

Comment: Not in the least, I'll try to remember that.

Comment: Thanks! Next doubt is that I dont understand what you are refering  saying that for $M= \oplus M_{\alpha}$   what you mean that the $\alpha$ have been chosen to index a representative set of isomorphism types of simple submodules of $M$? @rschwieb

Comment: Think you are taking only considering de $M_{\alpha}$ arising from isomophic copies of the simple summands in the original semisimple descomposition of M into simples right @rschwieb

Comment: That is for the original semisimple descomposition $M=S_{1} \oplus.... \oplus S_{n}$ Im cosidering $M_{\alpha} \cong S_{\alpha}$ for each $\alpha \in 1,,,n$ ? @rschwieb

Comment: No, $M_\alpha$ is not isomorphic to $S_\alpha$.  $M_\alpha$ is a *sum of copies of $S_\alpha$.*

Comment: Almost done ! Just struggling to prove $M_{\alpha}$ is simple. This is equivalent to prove for every $x,y \in M_{\alpha}$  there is a $f \in End(M)$ such $f$ maps $x$ into $y$ . Any hint how to construct this $f$ ?@rschwieb

Comment: Yes, this is indeed the part that requires the most work.  The approach I've been outlining to you is to go this route: $End_R(S_\alpha)=D$ is a division ring (since $S_\alpha$ is $R$-simple) and therefore $End_R(M_\alpha)$ is a ring of $D$-linear transformations of $M_\alpha$ and is a subring of $End_R(M)$.  In fact, you only need elements of this subring to show $M_\alpha$ is a simple $R$ module.  That is why I'm saying "if you can prove an $F$ vector space $V$ is always simple as a $End(V_F)$ module, then you are done."

Comment: Thanks! Already working in your idea, I will let you now if I got stuck. By the way you want to meant $M_{\alpha}$ is a simple as a T module not R module right? @rschiwieb

Comment: yes, you’re right about that typo.

Comment: Seems like intermediate steps are not so easy to prove. I dont see directly why  having $D= End_{R}(S_{\alpha})$ division ring implies $End_{R}(M_{\alpha})$ is a ring of $D$ linear transformations of itself also why this is also a division ring in order to use the lemma you claimed @rschwieb

Comment: Also, how is $M_{\alpha}$ a vector space over $End_{R}(M_{\alpha})$ ? @rschwieb

Comment: That $End_R(S_\alpha)$ is a division ring is trivial: Schur's Lemma. If $M_\alpha\cong \oplus_{i\in I}N_i$, then $End(M_\alpha)\cong \prod_{i\in I}\sum_{i\in I}End_R(N_i)$, and remember $End_R(N_i)=D$ for every $N_i$.  I never said it was easy... in fact I repeatedly said it's the hardest part.  I wish I had a simpler route but until now I haven't seen one.

Comment: So what this told me about the structure of $End(M_{\alpha})$? What is it the product of sum of division rings? Is it again a Division Ring? @rschwieb

Comment: Also how is $M_{\alpha} \cong \oplus N_{ i \in I} $ if I just defined as a sum  ? @rschwieb

Comment: Also how is $M_{\alpha} \cong \oplus N_{ i \in I} $ if I just defined as a sum  ? @rschwieb

Comment: It tells you that $M_\alpha$ is a simple $End(M_\alpha)$ module, hence a simple $End(M)$ module.  $End(M_\alpha)$ is certainly not necessarily a division ring. It is precisely what I said: a ring of linear transformations over a vector space.  I'm just appealing to the fact that $V_k$ is a simple $End(V_k)$ module for any division ring $k$.

Comment: I don't understand your comment about "how is $M_\alpha\cong \oplus N_i$. "  I thought that's how we agreed to define these.

Comment: Do you mean you don't know why a sum of mutually isomorphic simple modules can always be expressed as a direct sum of mutually isomorphic simple modules?

Comment: How that argument works? Product of sums of division rings are simple? @rschwieb

Comment: No, it's not like that and I admit I did not explain that well.  You have seen the proof that $End_R(S^n)\cong M_n(End_R(S))$ for a simple $R$ module $S$, right? This is the same thing except that you may have infinitely many copies of $S$ instead of just $n$.  This means you get a ring of row-finite (or column-finite) matrices.

Comment: This is the part where Im really getting problems following you, First im not sure why $End(M_{\alpha})=\otimes_{i \in I} \sum_{i \in I}End(N_{i})$ I have and idea but think there a lot of  fine steps going on on that isomorphism. But lets suppose I  got that isomorphism still doesnt know why we got into matrices.

Comment: First step, I need to prove that if a division ring $K$, then $V_{K}$ is simple as $V_{K}$ module but think you mention first this was for $V_{K}$ over a field? Also I dont see how you conclude $End(M_{\alpha})$ is simple over $End(M_{\alpha})$ via the isomorphism

Comment: (For $End(V_k)$) No, it doesn't have to be a field, just a division ring.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104820/discussion-between-cos-and-rschwieb).

Answer (score 2):

> But what I need to kill the original problem is to show that $$ is left simple module over $$ ...

But you can't. It's not true. For a field $F$, $M=F\times F$ is a semisimple $F$ module, where both $F\times \{0\}$ and $\{0\}\times F$ are simple $F$ submodules of $M_F$, but neither one is an $End(M_F)\cong M_2(F)$ module, simple or not.  But notice that both submodules are isomorphic as $F$ modules, and their sum *is* an $End(M_F)$ module: a simple one, in fact, showing $M$ is a semisimple $End(M_F)$ module.

That is part of the reason in your [last post on this subject](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3518672/29335) that I said you need to gather up the simple $R$ submodules that are $R$-isomorphic, because they form components which *are* the simple $T$ submodules you are looking for.